# Subquery na cláusula select com Criteria JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

Estava pesquisando como fazer uma subquery na cláusula select com Criteria de um select desse tipo:

```
SELECT tabela1.*,tabela2.*,
(SELECT MAX(tabela5.AtrDatatabela5) 
FROM .Tabela3 AS tabela3 
    INNER JOIN Tabela4 AS tabela4 ON tabela4.AtrIdTabela4 = tabela3.AtrIdTabela4
    LEFT outer JOIN CraMar AS tabela5 ON tabela5.AtrIdTabela4 = tabela4.AtrIdTabela4
WHERE  tabela4.AtrIdTipoTabela4 = 1
    AND tabela3.AtrIdTabela2 = tabela2.atridTabela2 
    AND tabela3.AtrDataDevolucao IS NULL
    AND tabela5.AtrDataTabela5 between 'Mar 29 2016 00:00' and 'Mar 29 2016 23:59'
    AND tabela5.AtrCodigoTabela5 IN ('E', 'S')) as utlimaTabela5
FROM Tabela1 AS tabela1...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O JPA 2.0 [não suporta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4669517/2387977) sub-query na cláusula SELECT. Veja se consegue alterar seu SQL original para conseguir o mesmo resultado sem precisar desta sub-query. A partir daí, fica mais fácil fazer uma consulta equivalente com Criteria.